# How can I overlay images with transparencies over a background (which is an image, too) using Python, tkinter, and PIL

Tags: python, image, tkinter, python-imaging-library

If the pics that are supossed to go on the upper layers have transparencies, but they show up with a gray square instead of the said transparency, covering the background.

I am coding a pinball game in Python, using Tkinter and PIL. I'm stuck because I need to display the elements of the game (flippers, bumpers, etc) over a background, however, when I try to overlay them, they show up with a gray square, instead of the transparency they already have.

This is the code:

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


#SecciÃ�Â³n funciones
def botones():
    juego_Nuevo_Boton = Button( menu_Principal, text = ("Juego nuevo"), command = juegoNuevo, font = ("Arial Black", 10), width = 20).place(x = 15, y = 125 )
    continuar_Juego_Boton = Button( menu_Principal, text = "Continuar juego",  font = ("Arial Black", 10), width = 20) .place(x = 15, y = 160)
    cerrar_El_Juego = Button( menu_Principal, text = "Cerrar el juego", command = menu_Principal.destroy, font = ("Arial Black", 10), width = 20).place(x = 15, y = 195 )

def juegoNuevo():
    ventana_Juego_Nuevo = Toplevel()
    ventana_Juego_Nuevo.geometry("600x700")
    ventana_Juego_Nuevo.title("Nueva partida")
    imagen_Fondo_Juego_Nuevo = PhotoImage( file = "fondo_Juego.gif" )
    fondo_Juego_Nuevo = Label(ventana_Juego_Nuevo, image=imagen_Fondo_Juego_Nuevo)
    fondo_Juego_Nuevo.place( x = 0, y = 0, relwidth = 1, relheight = 1 )
    fondo_Juego_Nuevo.image = imagen_Fondo_Juego_Nuevo
    imagen_lanzador_Canal = PhotoImage( file = "LanzadorCanal.gif" )
    Lanzador_Canal = Label(ventana_Juego_Nuevo, image = imagen_lanzador_Canal)
    Lanzador_Canal.place( x = 0, y = 0 )
    Lanzador_Canal.image = imagen_lanzador_Canal
    ############################################
    #I ALSO TRIED THIS BUT IT SHOWS UP SOME KIND OF IMAGE EDITOR CALLED "IMAGE MAGIC",
    #I don't need to edit the pictures, i just need them overlayed, so i can finish the game.

    #fondo_Del_Juego = Image.open("fondo_Juego.png")
    #lanzador_Canal = Image.open("LanzadorCanal.png")
    #fondo_Del_Juego.paste(lanzador_Canal, (0, 0), lanzador_Canal)
    #fondo_Del_Juego.show()
    #############################################
    ventana_Juego_Nuevo.mainloop()
#Crear pantalla y titulo

menu_Principal =  Tk()
menu_Principal.title("Pinball - Proyecto : creado por Daniel Bonilla")
menu_Principal.geometry("200x400")
imagen_Fondo_Menu = PhotoImage(file = "MenuPrincipal.gif")
fondo_Menu = Label(menu_Principal, image = imagen_Fondo_Menu)
fondo_Menu.place( x = 0, y = 0, relwidth = 1, relheight = 1 )
botones()

#Llamado a la ventana
menu_Principal.mainloop()
```

Pay special attention to "JuegoNuevo()" function, there's where the problem is.

So, pretty  much, this picture sums up my problem:

[image]

*The spring is transparent already, it just doesn't show up that way.

Have in mind that, later on, I need to put all the other elements, collisions,etc... so, that "Image Magic" thing (see the code above), I think, won't work.

*EDIT: I already tried as mentioned in the first answer with PNG files, but the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Use `png` instead of `gif` files  will fix your problem. Also remove the unused packages:

```
 from PIL import Image, ImageTk
```

Comment: I have already used PNG, GIF, JPG, ICO, and the same happens with all those formats :').

Comment: I tried your code with my png files and it works correctly :D

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try, maybe it's because I have converted all of those pics from JPG, to the aforementioned formats, including PNG; I'll try with "naturally-made" png pics.

Comment: @DanielBonillaJaramillo it's highly likely that when you converted from JPG you lost the transparency information. You can use a free program like the GIMP to add a new transparency channel. Probably white, but it could be another color if you want white in your image to be opaque.